# Как парсить json файл со множеством обьектов в Java?

Tags: java, json

Есть файл содержание которого

```
   {
"5447a9cd4bdc2dbd208b4567": {
    "id": "5447a9cd4bdc2dbd208b4567",
    "name": "ololo 1",
    "shortName": "1"
},
"5447ac644bdc2d6c208b4567": {
    "id": "5447ac644bdc2d6c208b4567",
    "name": "ololo 2",
    "shortName": "2"
},
"5448ba0b4bdc2d02308b456c": {
    "id": "5448ba0b4bdc2d02308b456c",
    "name": "ololo 3",
    "shortName": "3"
}}
```

Онлайн парсеры парсят нормально.
Хочу использовать GSON но так и не понял как розпарсить именно такой способ записи.
Костыли типа разделить по "}," и парсить как отдельные обьекты использовать не хочу потому что должен быть способ как это нормально сделать

**Решение**
Я думал что в файле просто список обьектов но оказалось что это мапа. Парсить такие файлы, если они вам попадутся, нужно как Map<String,Object>

Comment: а что за "именно такой способ записи"? Самый обычный джейсон вроде.

Comment: ну хорошо как из него вытянуть все обьекты в список?

Comment: В данном JSON для одного ключа `5447a9cd4bdc2dbd208b4567` находится два разных значения.  Какой результат ожидается?

Comment: этот ключ только один. Задача кажется банальной, всего лишь json обьект внутри которого другие обьекты но они не в массиве. Онлайн парсеры справляются именно так как надо - парсят этот файл как обьект с кучей обьектов, но как это Java пояснить и в частности GSONу

Comment: Хотя кажется понял - нужно парсить как мапу где ключ "5448ba0b4bdc2d02308b456c": а значение сам обект за ключем